# Visual Studio Community crashes with intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I use my VS Community 2013 to create my projects, VS Community crashes on CSS class intellisense.

I got following event errors:

**.NET ERROR**

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CompletionSession.get_CompletionSets()
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Html.BootstrapLogoCompletion+<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetEntries>b__0()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

**Application Error**

```
Naam van toepassing met fout: devenv.exe, versie: 12.0.31101.0, tijdstempel: 0x54548724
Naam van module met fout: unknown, versie: 0.0.0.0, tijdstempel: 0x00000000
Uitzonderingscode: 0xc0000005
Foutmarge: 0x1e9d8c75
Id van proces met fout: 0x7ab0
Starttijd van toepassing met fout: 0x01d03e448222c33b
Pad naar toepassing met fout: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Pad naar module met fout: unknown
Rapport-id: cfe83e00-aa37-11e4-8260-8019349818a8
Volledige pakketnaam met fout: 
Relatieve toepassings-id van pakket met fout:
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you installed the latest service packs for VS? Presently its Update 4. It might help installing the patch after verifying what Service pack you currently have

Comment: Looking at your callstack MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Html.BootstrapLogoCompletion, it seems there is some extension that is causing the crash. Can you disable this extension and see if that helps?

Comment: Problem is solved! There was a bugfix with Web essentials 2013. Bug fix release for 2.5 Nov 17. 2014: Fixes a crash in HTML class attributes